Simple painting, seal and characters identification
It looks like a painting from the beginning of the 20th century:




This is a guess - 清秀窈窕.

Maybe 清芬窅窕. Anyway, the seal is too unclear to make out.

清芬窅窕

Note: The displayed character 窅 is created by manually combining the resulting characters 穴 and 目 from the linked online tool.
https://www.handwritingtopng.com/chinese/generator/Cursive_Script_generator.php
